# how to get 3d space coordinates from 2d coordinates using python?

Tags: python, math, image-processing, point-cloud-library, 3d-model

I'm having a 2d orthomosaic image and also its point cloud. If I draw a polygon around an object on an image then in the output it should return me the coordinates of that object from 3d point cloud. As soon as I get the coordinates of the object from 3d cloud I want to calculate the volume of that object.
Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Assuming that the coordinates of the points are available in the same coordinate frame as the mosaic (plus Z), you need to find all points the XY projection of which falls inside the polygon. For efficiency, you may use acceleration techniques such as a hierarchy of bounding boxes. Computing the volume is challenging as you need to reconstruct a surface. You may try by triangulation of the 2D points and summing the volumes of the corresponding 3D prisms.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the corresponding point of orthomosaic image from point cloud isn’t trivial as it may seem, since in a digital image, what you have is pixel with a ‘location’ represented by row and column index, while in point cloud data, each point has a (X, Y, Z) value pair, which is coordinate measured in real-world coordinate system.

So what you need is uniforming the coordinates between image and point cloud. For orthomosaic image (assume it is generated from some commonly used software), it should be a tiff file with a transformation rule defined in its meta data. This transformation rule can transform image pixel coordinate  `i, j` into world coordinate `X, Y`.

These transformation rule, named ‘Geotransform’,  is usually defined by a transformation matrix, and can be retrieved from the meta data using library such as GDAL:
(***Make sure the coordinate system geotransform targets is the exact system your point cloud data is, otherwise, a point cloud registration is needed***)

```
from osgeo import GDAL

def get_geotransform(path: str):
    img = gdal.Open(path, 0)    # orthomosaic image path
    return img.GetGeoTransform()
```

The method above returns a `(6, )` size array, containing six transformation parameters.

GDAL official docs has [a good article](https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html) on how to use these parameters. If you want to transform multiple points, I’ve also implemented a vectorized approach (use at your own risk):

```
geotransform = get_geotransform(sample_img)

trans_matrix = np.array([[geotransform[2], geotransform[5]], [geotransform[1], geotransform[4]]])

XY = xy @ trans_matrix + np.array([geotransform[0], geotransform[3]])
```

Here, `xy` is a `(N, 2)` ndarray containing `(row, col)` index in each row.

So we get the world coordinate X, Y from the process above, now we need to search in the point cloud data for the closest point to X, Y, since there’s no guarantee that after the transformation, you can find the exact same point entry in point cloud data.

You can achieve this goal in a bunch of ways, even a brute force search can do the job, though considering overall efficiency, I suggest use the [KD-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) data structure. Suppose your point cloud data is a `(N, 3)` size ndarray, and you can fit a KDTree using `scikit-learn`:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

kd_tree = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1)
kd_tree.fit(cloud[:, 0: 2])
```

And get the nearest point cloud entry index:

```
nearest_point_index = kd_tree.kneighbors(XY, return_distance=False)
```

Accessing point cloud data with this index should give you the most approximate coordinate for the image point you selected.

**In conclusion**, two steps are needed:

- Transform the image point index to the world coordinate system
- Perform a least distance search through the point cloud to find the corresponding coordinate

**Also**, the code above is just for pure demonstration, and should be adjusted for your own using scenario. For example, if you just need to query for a small amount of points and your point cloud data is very large, KD-Tree method may be less efficient overall, more details are needed to answer this question more specifically.

Comment: I'd rather use a rectangle query than nearest neighbors, using the axis-aligned bounding box of the polygon. Then filter the candidate points with a full point-in-polygon test.

Comment: While I havn't done test myself, the point query solution from @YvesDaoust should indeed be more suitable for this specific task.